# Debugging Rails and Trinidad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, trinidad-gem, rdebug

I'm working on a rails 3 app that uses trinidad. I've been using RubyMine(4.5), but can't for the life of me figure out how to debug the app. It runs fine from the IDE in non-debug mode, but when you try to debug it says that it can't debug trinidad apps. Why does it say this?

I have also tried running trinidad and rdebug from the command line and then attach to it from RubyMine using a remote debug config. I am able to attach but I can't set any breakpoints. And also changes to ruby code don't appear to be taking affect without restarting.

I thought I'd mostly worked around these problems by using Webrick when debugging from RubyMine. In which case I am able to set and hit breakpoints, but still for some reason any changes I make to ruby code do not take affect until I restart the server. In fact the only way I'm able to change ruby code on-the-fly is when I'm running the app in non-debug mode.

So what I'd like to be able to do is: use trinidad from RubyMine to debug and also be able to change ruby code on the fly. Or, if that's not possible, use Webrick from RubyMine and also be able to change code on-the-fly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the [EAP version of RubyMine](http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2012/12/enjoy-rubymine-enoki-eap-while-were-all-still-alive/), debugging should work better for this configuration (**TorqueBox and Trinidad Run/Debug Support**).

UPDATE: RubyMine 5.0 with Trinidad support is [released](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/index.html).